# Automatically mount drives when debian server reboots

Tags: debian, amazon-web-services, mount, disk-volume

I have a Debian server (which is a AWS EC2 Instance) and I have multiple AWS volumes attached to the server, which are all mounted in `/mnt`. However if I ever reboot the server (which happens whenever I create an AMI image), when it reboots all the drives are no longer mounted. I can easily remount them but I am a little concerned that it may get rebooted by someone else in the future so I was wondering if there was a way to automate the mounting.

Comment: Note: I'm aware of the no-reboot option when making AMIs, but that's not the point ;)

Comment: Is this a virtual server?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry AWS = Amazon Web Services. So yea! Does it make a difference though?

Comment: @Downvoter, care to share a reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is configured in [`/etc/fstab`](https://wiki.debian.org/fstab) using the `auto` option.

Comment: `auto` is included in `defaults`.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the `/etc/fstab` file. `man fstab` for more information about setting it up.